# SMS API not working on my Hostinger server but working properly with localhost

Tags: php, php-curl

AM having below code for send sms is working properly on localhost without any kind of issue but not server it just shows below ERROR

> cURL ERROR: 28 Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds

```
define("SMS_URL_TEXT","http://sms.stayintouch.co.in/api/sendhttp.php");

function SendSMS($recipients,$sms_message)
{
    
    $url = SMS_URL_TEXT;    
    $param = array(
        'authkey' => SMS_AUTH_KEY,
        'mobiles' => implode(',', $recipients),
        'sender' => SMS_SENDER,
        'message' => $sms_message ,
        'route' => '4',
        'country' => '0'
        );
    
    
    
    $result="1";
    $post = '';
    foreach ($param as $key => $val) 
    {
        $post .= '&' . $key . '=' . rawurlencode($val);
    }
    

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Connection: close"));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) 
    {
        $result = "cURL ERROR: " . curl_errno($ch) . " " . curl_error($ch);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        switch($returnCode) 
        {
        case 200 :
        break;
        default :
        $result = "HTTP ERROR: " . $returnCode;
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

SendSMS($recipients=array("919327133788"),$sms_message="test message developer");
```

Comment: Are you certain you have the api key stored where it should be in your deployment?

Comment: Yes i have stored it for security reason i haven't placed here